# TypeError: stats.jsonToString is not a function Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am making a pipeline on VSTS, added webpack into my yaml file and it is erroring on that task:
##[error]TypeError: stats.jsonToString is not a function. Is there any way setup a webpack 5 in azure vsts?

My package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "production": "webpack --progress --json --mode production --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

---

My Pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'Hosted VS2017'
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - npm

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Solution)'
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    workingDir: ''

- task: webpack@4
  displayName: webpack
  inputs:
    webpackCliArguments: '--config webpack.config.js'
    treatErrorsAs: 'errors'
    treatWarningsAs: 'warnings'
    workingFolder: ''

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'

- task: PublishSymbols@1
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
  continueOnError: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'Drop'
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your pipeline?

Comment: Hi, I've just added my pipeline
tried also: 
node ".\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js" --json --mode production --output-path "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\dist"

From https://github.com/Dealogic/webpack-vsts-extension/issues/95
but it says it  doesn't recognise node command
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the similar [issue](https://github.com/Dealogic/webpack-vsts-extension/issues/95) you shared, there are two workarounds:

1. Add a [Yarn](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn) task with the same command and args as local.
2. Use a CMD task with follwoing command.

   ```
   node ".\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js" --json --mode production --output-path "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\dist"
   ```

When it doesn't recognise node command, please install with [Node.js Tool task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops).

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0 
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 13.x

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'node --version'
```